# Zabbix Enable Item option only for Super Admins

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-custom-reports

I  am using zabbix 6.4 and i want to give enable/disable of items/triggers/hosts only to users with super admin access, Please help with required changes

I tries to user permissions but that don't seem to work, Please check if any code level changes are required

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this in Zabbix, you need to modify the user group permissions and set up access restrictions accordingly. Here's a step-by-step guide:

Create a new User Group:

1. Go to "Administration" > "User groups."
2. Click on "Create user group" and give it a name, like "Super Admins."

Configure User Group Permissions:

1. In the newly created "Super Admins" user group, you can grant the desired permissions, which include "Read-write" access to items, triggers, and hosts. Make sure that only this user group has these permissions.

Assign Users to the User Group:

4. Go to "Administration" > "Users."
5. Edit the user account you want to grant super admin access.
   6 )Under the "Groups" tab, add the user to the "Super Admins" user group.

By following these steps, users belonging to the "Super Admins" user group will have read-write access to items, triggers, and hosts, while other users will have restricted access based on their respective user groups.

Comment: First of all thanks for the contribution. But we have already tried this doesn't work, we want to only revoke the enable and disable option , but can user should be able to create host , items and trigger.
Please do help us in case you know about the same.

Comment: Okay, I see your worry, however, please be aware that Zabbix does not have the ability to regulate the enable and deactivate while permitting host creation. 

To accomplish the same, you must edit the Zabbix code. Make sure the person has a strong knowledge because making code-level modifications is complex and requires thorough comprehension.

Comment: Thanks Vishal, Do you now anyone, with this type of knowledge

Comment: Krishan such a question should not be asked here as the StackOverflow community does not allow it. Also, if you satisfy with my answer please flag it right!